# Problems with joystick tutorial

Tags: ros, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the tutorial "ConfiguringALinuxJoystick#Starting_the_Joy_Node" on Ubuntu 11.4 with ROS electric.  Everything is good until I run the joy node.  I get an error [ WARN] [1323609269.393225314]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1323609269.393347028]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]

Any help would be appreciated,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12303/problems-with-joystick-tutorial/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what I was doing wrong.  I was in the wrong directory

Morpheus

---

Originally posted by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) with karma: 111 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2014-11-25**:
Do you know how to use a normal joystick to control a turtlebot based kobuki?I have some trouble with it . I refer to this website:http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/hydro/Joystick%20Teleop.